# WIll my packaged jar using Maven have my modified jar dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, packet-sniffers

I'm creating a packet sniffer in java using the Pcap4j library, Netbeans and Maven. I need to modify some of the functions and what they output since I'm creating a GUI application and the current function outputs are making life very difficult. So when i finally package it using Maven, will the jar generated contain my modified Pcap4j dependency? I need to execute that jar on another PC for my final presentation. Or are my concepts about maven packaging completely wrong? If so, please enlighten me. Cheers!

Comment: I cannot really follow your workflow. Is the following correct? You checked out the code of a third party library, modified it, build it with Maven and used it as a dependency in your own project?

Comment: @JFMeier Yep,that's right.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify a third-party project and build it with Maven, you should give it a version number that indicates just that (like `1.2.3-patched-SNAPSHOT` or `1.2.3-modified-SNAPSHOT`). Then you can reference it with this version number and be sure that you get what you want.

Comment: What would happen when i run it on a new machine? I mean, run my final generated jar file. Will it auto download all the dependencies and then run my edited version of the dependency? If not, how do i ensure that?

Comment: If you just build a jar file, all the dependencies are missing and it will not run. You need to bundle or reference the dependencies to make it work. One way is to build a fat jar with the maven assembly plugin or the maven shade plugin.

Comment: Yes, sorry i meant the shaded plugin. I used that and packaged my entire project. how about then?

Comment: With the maven shade plugin, the dependencies are packaged into the jar, they are not downloaded from somewhere. So what you build is what you run.

Comment: Alright, so if i run them on a new machine which doesn't have any of those dependencies downloaded, will i have to ensure that they're pre-downloaded or will simply executing my jar file do that for me?

Comment: Sorry, maybe we talk about different things, but: When you build a fat jar with the maven shade plugin, it includes all dependencies. So you only need to copy that jar to a machine with java and run it. All dependencies already in the jar file.

Comment: Okay, so one of the pre requisites to run Pcap4J is to have npcap or winpcap installed. SO if a host machine has nothing but java installed, will my fat jar still work?

Comment: Are these jars that you reference as `<dependency>` in your POM, or are these external programs?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response but yes they are referenced as dependencies.

Comment: All your dependencies are packaged into your fat jar. So everywhere you run your jar (with java), you have all your dependencies. No need to redownload, install or otherwise manage them.

Comment: Yeah that's right. But i ran it on a host machine with only java installed, and it turns out that the host machine needs to have all the dependencies installed too in order for my application to work. So, the answer to my question is actually no, the jar won't take care of downloading the dependencies in a new machine which doesn't have them pre-installed.

Comment: What makes you think you need to "install" the dependencies on the new machine? Which error occured when you did not do it?

Comment: I ran my jar but it didn't work because the machine didn't have the pcap4j,winpcap and jbdc driver installed. I don't remember the exact errors but they were logged in cmd as 'modules not found'.

Comment: It would be really important to analyse the exact error messages. If you get something like "Class not found", then you probably did not package the dependency into the final shaded jar.

Comment: I will run it again and check the exact error message. I wa giving my final presentation and realized that i didn't have to port it to another machine and run it so i just rain it once hastily for my benefit to see and then forgot all about it. I will get back to you about this.